# Why an observatory keeps being used as a location to advance plot in Hannibal?

Tags: props, hannibal-tv

In the TV show Hannibal, an obsolete observatory is used on multiple occasions to advance the plot:

- A female FBI trainee severed hand holding a cell phone is found at this station
- Dr. Chilton is captured and has his organs surgically taken out at this station by Dr. Gillan
- Katz's body is discovered in this station

I understand given its remote location, it is easier to be used as a hideout for criminal activities, but is there any other reasons?

Comment: It's also a metaphor -- "To observe and show others" is what Hannibal does best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, Gideon is trying to get the attention of The Chesapeake Ripper.

In the third case it is Hannibal Lecter "taunting" Will and Jack, sending them a message (by  having her get pulled apart the way she pulls apart a crime scene).

Answer (score 1):

The choice to use this site was likely nothing more than having an opportunity to use this interesting location that had recently become available.

[image: David Dunlap Observatory. Observatory dome to the left and large stone building to the right.]

The [David Dunlap Observatory - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Dunlap_Observatory), was decommissioned by the University of Toronto because of light pollution.

It then became a convenient location for several programs, including *Hannibal*, *Warehouse 13*, *The Umbrella Academy*, *Good Witch*, *Odd Squad*, *Universe*, and *Communist Mummies from Mars*.
(See [Movies Filmed at David Dunlap Observatory — MovieMaps](https://moviemaps.org/locations/3sk)).

On *Hannibal*, the site's main building also served as the Baltimore State Hospital for the Criminally Insane.

Dr. Hannibal's office building was played by St. Andrew’s Church Manse, built in 1873 at 75 Simcoe Street, seen here in Google's interactive street view (take a look around):

[image: Large Victorian style house]